# React Query suspense triggers top level loading.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query, react-suspense

I am using a query-level `suspense:true` flag inside a component.

```js
 const { data: { formattedJournal, journalEntryId } = {}, isError } = useQuery(
    {
      queryKey: ['journal', selectedDate],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/journal/${selectedDate}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
      },
      suspense: true,
    },
  );
```

When I change `selectedDate` from a datepicker, instead of the suspense loader being shown in the child:

```
 <Suspense fallback={<TableSkeleton></TableSkeleton>}>
        <JournalTable
          formattedJournal={formattedJournal}
        />
 </Suspense>
```

It instead shows the top-level `loading.jsx`. The only time I see the `tableSkeleton` is on a cold load of the page, every subsequent re-fetch of the `/journal/[date]` resource triggers the full-page loader in `loading.jsx`, and I don't understand why.

Comment: is the useQuery usage in the `JournalTable` component?